# DeepSpeech-Polyglot: Signals.SIGSEGV: 11

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

I'm trying to generate the scorer of the DeepSpeech-Polyglot-Project. I have followed every step of the documentation but when i run:

```
python3 /DeepSpeech/data/lm/generate_lm.py --input_txt /DeepSpeech/data_prepared/texts/${LANGUAGE}/clean_vocab.txt --output_dir /DeepSpeech/data_prepared/texts/${LANGUAGE}/ --top_k 500000 --kenlm_bins /DeepSpeech/native_client/kenlm/build/bin/ --arpa_order 5 --max_arpa_memory "85%" --arpa_prune "0|0|1" --binary_a_bits 255 --binary_q_bits 8 --binary_type trie --discount_fallback
```

I get the following error:

```
Saving top 500000 words ...

Calculating word statistics ...
  Your text file has 202185630 words in total
  It has 2106729 unique words
  Your top-500000 words are 98.7433 percent of all words
  Your most common word "die" occurred 7853080 times
  The least common word in your top-k is "adamantium" with 5 times
  The first word with 6 occurrences is "begibst" at place 448270

Creating ARPA file ...
=== 1/5 Counting and sorting n-grams ===
Reading /DeepSpeech/data_prepared/texts/de/lower.txt.gz
----5---10---15---20---25---30---35---40---45---50---55---60---65---70---75---80---85---90---95--100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/DeepSpeech/data/lm/generate_lm.py", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/DeepSpeech/data/lm/generate_lm.py", line 201, in main
    build_lm(args, data_lower, vocab_str)
  File "/DeepSpeech/data/lm/generate_lm.py", line 97, in build_lm
    subprocess.check_call(subargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/DeepSpeech/native_client/kenlm/build/bin/lmplz', '--order', '5', '--temp_prefix', '/DeepSpeech/data_prepared/texts/de/', '--memory', '85%', '--text', '/DeepSpeech/data_prepared/texts/de/lower.txt.gz', '--arpa', '/DeepSpeech/data_prepared/texts/de/lm.arpa', '--prune', '0', '0', '1', '--discount_fallback']' died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>.
```

I'm using this documentation: https://gitlab.com/Jaco-Assistant/deepspeech-polyglot

I am thankful for every hint.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed on [DeepSpeech's Discourse.](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/error-when-creating-my-own-scorer-file/62139/9)

Basically your KenLM is not installed right. Search just for the error on Google and you'll find that you have to reinstall and check your environment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the answer on Discourse.

I tried to reinstall KenLM as followed:

`git clone https://github.com/kpu/kenlm`

`cd kenlm`

`mkdir build`

`cd build`

`apt install build-essential cmake libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev libeigen3-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev`

`cmake ..`

`make -j 4`

To be sure that I'm not missing something I also added

`pip install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip`

It always installs `kenlm-0.0.0`is that normal or did i mess something up?

Comment: Ah, don't use the pip version. This is definitely the problem. You will have to build it yourself, try this: https://medium.com/tekraze/install-kenlm-binaries-on-ubuntu-language-model-inference-tool-33507000f33